# install pinax from an index link via pip from a pypi mirror

Tags: python, django, pip, pinax

I wanted to install pinax and other dependent packages listed at

http://pypi.pinaxproject.com 
I try with the following settings in the requirements file:

```
django-notification==0.1.4
django-openid==0.2.0
django-email-confirmation==0.1.3
django-mailer==0.1.0
django-announcements==0.1.0
django-pagination==1.0.5.1
django-timezones==0.1.4
django-ajax-validation==0.1.3
django-uni-form==0.6.0
template_utils==0.4p2
django-staticfiles==0.1.2

--index-url http://pypi.pinaxproject.com
--index-url http://pypi2.pinaxproject.com
```

and then

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Other packages get installed but the above two lines are ignored what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `--extra-index-url`:

```
--extra-index-url http://pypi.pinaxproject.com
--extra-index-url http://pypi2.pinaxproject.com
```

You should only use `--index-url` when you wish to replace the official PyPI. The parameter `--extra-index-url` adds additional PyPI repositories to install packages from and it still allows you to install packages from the official PyPI (unless, of course, you only wish to use a mirror, then `--index-url` is appropriate).

See [requirements.txt documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) for more information.

Comment: @user993563: *how* does it not work? What did you expect and what happened instead?

Comment: i expected pinax to be installed but it does not get installed, along with other files. If you have time, try installing in a dummy virtualenv and you will figure things for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`--index-url` is a one-value option; every time you specify it on the command line, the previous value get's overwritten.

Use `--extra-index-url` instead:

> --extra-index-url=URL
>    Extra URLs of package indexes to use in addition to --index-url

From the [install documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#install-packages):

> If you have your own package index with a few additional packages, you may want to to specify additional index URLs while still also using PyPI:
>
> $ pip install --extra-index-url http://my.package.repo/ SomePackage

Comment: what if i want to install all the packages on the page listed on the url mentioned in the question.

Comment: That'd be a different question altogether :-) Best practice is for a main package to list dependencies in the setup_requires field and they will be automatically pulled in; this project doesn't and so you'll have to list each dependency explicitely.

Comment: i understand, but i am into a trouble and out here on SO looking for a fitting way out of it :)

Comment: Sure, I am also trying to teach you a little about how SO works here; better create a *new* question with the new problem; your original question was just about the use of `--index-url`.

Comment: please re read the question heading itself: *install pinax from an index link via pip from a pypi mirror*

Comment: It wasn't exactly clear that you wanted to use `--index-url http://pypi.pinaxproject.com` to express "install all packages from this URL". But that's just not how requirements.txt works. You can only install a list of packages and additionally add sources from which to install the packages.

Comment: I am not sure as to why it was not clear. Would you want to install a package without installing its dependency? Would you install django without installing Python, if both of them were listed to be installed at the same place. Its something that should be taken care of.

Comment: @user993563: you told us what you had tried, we saw a flaw in this (multiple --index-url entries, "what am I missing?") and answered accordingly.

Comment: the flaw and the subsequent correction by you did not affect end result.

Comment: Why the negative vote? I'd love to improve my answer, but I'd need feedback in the form of a comment for that!